# regular expression matches all string(include space) without kind of specific string contain

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a class in my Java source code, for example:

```
public class PersonMeta {
    private long id;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class PersonMeta2 {
}
```

For this code I should get to different classes in my result collection, **PersonMeta** and **PersonMeta2**.

```
//result0
public class PersonMeta {
    ...
}
//result1
public class PersonMeta2 {

}
```

So I tried this expression:

```
(public\s)?class\s\w+\s*{[\s\S]*}
```

But obviously it's incorect, it will meatch the whole file, so I tried to use **?**, but it's not what I want either, it will give me this:

```
public class PersonMeta {
        private long id;
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
```

So I think I need to write an expression like this:

```
(public\s)?class\s\w+\s*{_ThePatent_}
```

**_ThePatent_** should means that : any string or space **but not include** this patent(I know that it's not very strict, a string variable can also contain it, but please ignore it at first):

```
(public\s)?class\s\w+\s*{
```

I have read some question, and I tried to use like:

```
//Match every string without "abc"
(public\s)?class\s\w+\s*{((?!abc).)*}
```

It should work because there is no "abc" in my class, but it shouldn't, and I don't think it can match the space so I tried to optimize it to:

```
(public\s)?class\s\w+\s*{((?!abc)[\s\S])*}
```

But it gives to me the whole file.

So the question is how can I get what I want?

Comment: Even a regex for this kind of code parsing if exists, it breaks easily on edge cases.

Comment: I think patent is the wrong word here? I don't understand what that means. I also don't understand what would be an example for abc here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your classes are that simple with just attributes and default getters and setters, you can make sure that all the braces are balanced by having every opening brace after the class declaration be followed by a closing brace and then match the next closing brace as the end of the class. If you have nested braces, you could look into how recursive regexes work in Java.

`(?:public\s)?class\s(\w+)\s*{(?:[^{}]|{[^}]*})*}`

This will work on your example and save the class name in the first match group.

By the way, if you just want to match any character you can use `.` instead of `[\s\S]`.

Comment: Really thanks, it works for me, but I still cannot understand about what's the meaning of **?:**, I removed all of them, it still can work for me.